# Is there a way to customize 'vc-update'?

Tags: git, version-control

Currently, running `vc-update` in my Emacs runs `git pull`. Is there a way to customize it so that it runs something different like `git pull --prune`? Is it even advisable to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source of `vc-update` and `vc-git-pull` (the function that is called by `vc-update` when using a `git` backend), there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to *permanently* customize the pull command that gets run (short of redefining `vc-git-pull`).

However, a quick look at the documentation for `vc-update` (via <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `vc-update` <kbd>RET</kbd>) tells you:

> [...] On a distributed version control system, this runs a "pull"
>   operation to update the current branch, prompting for an argument
>   list if required.  **Optional prefix ARG forces a prompt.**

In other words, if you want to alter the pull command that `vc-update` uses, just prefix the call with <kbd>C-u</kbd>. You'll get a prompt that says:

```
Git pull command: git pull
```

You can then append `--prune` and hit <kbd>RET</kbd>.